# Json Escape Character Traversin

Tags: json, karate

I have a request on how to traverse a JSON (modified JSON with escaped characters) as below

```
{
"scenario Description": "send request end to end functional test",
"step Sequence": {
"description": "POC Send Request for payload",
"sequence": [
{
"type": "SEND",
"topic": "",
"header": {
"json": "{ "event Version": {"integer": "10"}}"
},
"payload": {
"source": "INLINE",
"json": "{"creditCorrdinatorIdentifier":"<Some identifier>","requestorIdentifier":"","servicingCenterCode":"6026","applicationSubmissionDate":"09/15/2022 10:55:44 AM","submitterIdentifier":"","applicationNumber":"17277238","creditRequestAmount":"< Some Value>","creditRequestAccountProductCode":"BOTB","creditRequestTypeCode":"113","creditRequestPurposeCode":"200","creditApplicationBorrower":{"soleProprietorPartyTaxGovernmentIssuedIdentifier":{"string":""},"soleProprietorPartyTaxGovernmentIssuedIdentfierTypeCode":{"string":""}"additionalRequestInfo":{"array":[{"map":{"l": additionalRequestInfo"}}]},"uploadedDocs":{"array":[{"map":{"b": uploadedDocs"}}]}}",
"schema": ""

    }
  }
]
}
}
```

My Question is how can I get application Number taken from this json and print it (How can I traverse thru this JSON to print "application Number" as "17277238" thru Karate frame work. ( I tried SET, Print, DEF key words)

Comment: if the linked answer does not help please use a minimal example next time